# Flatten hierarchy with networkx and append columns

Tags: networkx

I am using networkx to flatten a parent/child-hierarchy, which works good so far. However, I don't know how to add additional columns to the result.
This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['Unit A', 'Department Q', 'Lorem'],
    ['Unit A', 'Department R', 'Ipsum'],
    ['Unit A', 'Department S', 'dolor'],
        ['Department S', 'Office 1', 'sit'],
        ['Department S', 'Office 2', 'amet'],
    ['Unit B', 'Department X', 'consetetur'],
    ['Unit B', 'Department Y', 'sadipscing'],
    ['Unit B', 'Department Z', 'elitr'],
        ['Department Z', 'Office 3', 'sed'],
        ['Department Z', 'Office 4', 'diam'],
            ['Office 4', 'Place K', 'nonumy'] ,
            ['Office 4', 'Place L', 'eirmod']   
]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Parent', 'Child', 'Description'])
```

then creating the hieararchy and bring it to a df:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Parent', target='Child',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph, edge_attr=True,
                           )

roots = (v for v, d in G.in_degree() if d == 0)
leaves = [v for v, d in G.out_degree() if d == 0]

out = (pd.DataFrame(path for root in roots for path in
                    nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, leaves))
        .add_prefix('Node_')
      )

print(out)

   Node_0        Node_1    Node_2   Node_3
0  Unit A  Department Q      None     None
1  Unit A  Department R      None     None
2  Unit A  Department S  Office 1     None
3  Unit A  Department S  Office 2     None
4  Unit B  Department X      None     None
5  Unit B  Department Y      None     None
6  Unit B  Department Z  Office 3     None
7  Unit B  Department Z  Office 4  Place K
8  Unit B  Department Z  Office 4  Place L
```

But how to add the additional description column to the output?

Comment: How exactly do you want to generate the description for each column? Is it just supposed to be the description of the bottom of the heirarchy, or would you also want the description of the A->S connection in the row with index 2, for instance?

Comment: I just want to add any additional columns of the original df to the output - again as additional columns. As far as I understand, I can append them as attributes with edge_attr=True (which is what I did), however, no idea how I can retrieve them.

Comment: But there's no clear place where these descriptions belong. My question is where in this dataframe you think the description 'dolor' for the connection from unit A to deparment S should go

Comment: You can't "just add any additional columns of the original" if the columns of the original have a different length then the columns of the result.

Comment: OK, then, starting from scratch: how can I flatten a parent/child hierarchy, preserving all attributes (... and with multiple roots... and in an unbalanced hierarchy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modification of your script that allows us to meaningfully append those descriptions.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

data = [
    ['Unit A', 'Department Q', 'Lorem'],
    ['Unit A', 'Department R', 'Ipsum'],
    ['Unit A', 'Department S', 'dolor'],
        ['Department S', 'Office 1', 'sit'],
        ['Department S', 'Office 2', 'amet'],
    ['Unit B', 'Department X', 'consetetur'],
    ['Unit B', 'Department Y', 'sadipscing'],
    ['Unit B', 'Department Z', 'elitr'],
        ['Department Z', 'Office 3', 'sed'],
        ['Department Z', 'Office 4', 'diam'],
            ['Office 4', 'Place K', 'nonumy'] ,
            ['Office 4', 'Place L', 'eirmod']   
]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Parent', 'Child', 'Description'])

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Parent', target='Child',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph, edge_attr=True,
                           )

roots = (v for v, d in G.in_degree() if d == 0)
out = (pd.DataFrame(path for root in roots for path in
                    nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, df['Child']))
        .add_prefix('Node_')
      )
out['Description'] = df['Description']

print(out)
```

The result:

```
    Node_0        Node_1    Node_2   Node_3 Description
0   Unit A  Department Q      None     None       Lorem
1   Unit A  Department R      None     None       Ipsum
2   Unit A  Department S      None     None       dolor
3   Unit A  Department S  Office 1     None         sit
4   Unit A  Department S  Office 2     None        amet
5   Unit B  Department X      None     None  consetetur
6   Unit B  Department Y      None     None  sadipscing
7   Unit B  Department Z      None     None       elitr
8   Unit B  Department Z  Office 3     None         sed
9   Unit B  Department Z  Office 4     None        diam
10  Unit B  Department Z  Office 4  Place K      nonumy
11  Unit B  Department Z  Office 4  Place L      eirmod
```

Comment: Ahh... now I see my mistake. Thanks, Ben!

Comment: Sorry, need some follow-up: this will only work if the original tree is well-sorted. Otherwise this matching on index will not work. Eg. if I place a subnode to the beginning, this will not match with the original index. Any idea?

Comment: I don’t understand the issue you’re describing. Maybe you can edit your post to include a quick example where my approach goes wrong and explain what is undesirable about the result.

Comment: @Frank If you want to “sort” the tree, you might find the nx [dfs iterator](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_preorder_nodes.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_preorder_nodes) to be helpful